# como identar uma string para json

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho uma string no formato json.

Desta forma:

```html
{"IdLead":4186960,"Concessionaria":"Mila - Centro","DadosQualificacao":{"IdEvento":79654,"Qualificacao":1,"Motivo":6,"DescricaoMotivo":"motivo 1234","Ficha":["aaaaaaaa - TESTE","Ação desejada:=123456789 teste 132456789","Data Agendamento Test-Drive:=20/04/2018","Já é Cliente da Marca?=SIM"]},"DadosPessoa":{"Nome":"Guilherme Martins","Email":"filipe.lopes@t-systems.com.br","DDD":11,"Telefone":948831041,"CpfCnpj":"44436740803","PreferenciaContato":0}}
```

Preciso mostra essa string na minha tela, porém, ela aparece em uma linha mesmo. Gostaria de saber como identar essa string para mostrar no formato identato.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que não vale a pena você tentar construir um parser por si só. Há muitas coisas com o que lidar e já tem isso pronto.

Você pode criar um método que usa o reader e writer da biblioteca `Newtonsoft` e fazer a reescrita identada:

```
public class JsonFormatting
{
    public static string Ident(string json)
    {
        using (var sr = new StringReader(json))
            using (var sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                var jr = new JsonTextReader(sr);
                var jw = new JsonTextWriter(sw) { Formatting = Formatting.Indented };
                jw.WriteToken(jr);
                return sw.ToString();
            }
    }
}
```

Para usá-la, você fará assim:

```
string json = "{ \"Id\":123456, \"Content\":\"Seu json vai aqui...\"}";
string formatted = JsonFormatting.Ident(json);
```

[**Este exemplo está disponível no dotnetfiddle.**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RELxin)

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 3):

Com a biblioteca JSON.NET é possível criar uma instância da classe `JValue` a partir da *string* inicial e depois mostrar a representação deste objeto em *string* novamente usando a opção de formatação que respeita indentação.

Por exemplo:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var json = "{\"id\": 1, \"nome\": \"LINQ\"}";           
        var beauty = JValue.Parse(json).ToString(Formatting.Indented);
        Console.WriteLine(beauty);
    }
}
```

<sup>**[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hYh17P)**</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a biblioteca [JSON.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Exemplo do próprio site de como seria:

```
Product product = new Product();
product.Name = "Apple";
product.Expiry = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small" };

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
// {
//   "Name": "Apple",
//   "Expiry": "2008-12-28T00:00:00",
//   "Sizes": [
//     "Small"
//   ]
// }
```

Para identar só a string você pode usar:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { 'sua_string_aqui' });
```

Comment: Então Leticia, eu não tenho um objeto, eu tenho uma string já com o padrão JSON, porém no meu HTML desejo mostrar esse string nesse formato identado

Comment: @GuilhermeNunes use a tag `<pre>` que diz que o texto dentro dela já tem um formato a ser mostrado.

Comment: @Leticia: Assim não rolou; Ele assim formata um objeto em json, e se passar uma string ele apenas add um / entre os dados.

Comment: @Lucas, assim parece ser legal, porem ele quebra a linha aonde tem espaço, e essa minha stirng não tem espaço entre os dados...

Comment: @GuilhermeNunes provavelmente não é um espaço que ele tem e sim um `\n` (quebra de linha). Podes testar com `meuJson = meuJson.Replace("\n","")`

Comment: No site do JSON.Net que coloquei o link você acha vários exemplos de como fazer. Mas, segue aqui o link direto dos exemplos: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeObject.htm